# Programmatically remote control your mac (OS sierra or higher) from an API?

Tags: macos

Is there a way to programmatically remote control your mac (OS sierra or higher) from an API? As an example, here are 3 examples of what I'm looking to do: 
1. Remotely launch a Browser (Safari/Chrome, navigate to url and then type in a user/pwd to login and then maybe navigate to a few pages.
2. Remotely launch an app (Keynote) and then, click File->New, choose White Theme, and then type a few words on slide and save locally on the mac.

If anyone can share any frameworks, links or code to do this, that would be great!

Comment: Do you mean `teamviewer`, Remote Desktop, VNC, `ssh` or something else? How are you connected to the Mac?

Comment: No, not connected to the mac with any of the tools you mentioned. The mac will be connected to internet via wifi and want to control from a custom iOS app or web page from another computer's browser.

Comment: You may find macOS IFTT control to be helpful here https://abdyfran.co/projects/macos-ifttt